# Задача tkinter. Не выводится ответ

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

**Здравствуйте!
Пытаюсь решить задачу описанную на скриншоте, но при вводе значения в первое поле (1 или 2) и нажатия Enter не происходит событие для второго поля.**

[image: Задача tkinter]

```py
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
n = randint(1, 100)

def Raschet(event):
    a = otvet.get()
    if a == '1' and n % 2 == 1:
        otvet2.set('Правильно!')
    elif a == '2' and n % 2 == 0:
        otvet2.set('Правильно!')
    else:
        otvet2.set('Неправильно!')

root = Tk()
root.title('Чёт или нечет?')
root.resizable(False, False)

nadp1 = Label(root, text = 'Чёт или нечет?', font = 'Arial 12 bold')
nadp2 = Label(root, text = 'Компьютер загадал целое число', font = 'Arial 12')
ramka = Frame(root)
nadp3 = Label(ramka, text = 'Какое оно - четное (введите 2) или нечетное (введите 1)?', font = 'Arial 12')
otvet = StringVar()
pole1 = Entry(ramka, width = 1, textvariable = otvet)
otvet2 = StringVar()
pole2 = Entry(root, width = 20, textvariable = otvet2)

nadp1.pack()
nadp2.pack()
ramka.pack()
nadp3.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
pole1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
pole2.pack()

pole1.bind('Return', Raschet)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Название события должно указываться в угловых скобках:

```
pole1.bind('<Return>', Raschet)
```

Comment: Действительно! Спасибо огромное, а то сижу голову ломаю где же косяк =)

Answer (score 0):

`a = otvet.get()`
 замени на
 `a = pole1.get()`

`.get()` метод применяется к `Entry`

Comment: не помогло. В данном случае разницы нет, что напрямую к виджету обращаться или через связанную переменную.